Unable to Launch AVD in Android Studio with Emulator Warning About HAXM and Hypervisor Driver
I am trying to launch an Android Virtual Device (AVD) using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch, but the emulator fails to start. Here's the terminal output:
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.2.10.0 (build_id 12414864) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO    | Found systemPath D:\androidSDK\system-images\android-35\google_apis\x86_64\
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\ASUSΓäó\.android\avd\..\avd\Resizable_Experimental_API_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
HAXM is deprecated and not supported by Intel any more. Please download and install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors, which also supports Intel Processors. Installing from SDK Manager is coming soon.

What I’ve Tried:

Deleted the quickbootChoice.ini file in the AVD folder but still face the issue.
Verified that my virtualization (Intel VT-x) is enabled in BIOS.
Changed the graphics option in AVD Manager to Software (SwiftShader), but it didn’t help.
Checked for updates in SDK Manager but could not find a direct option for the Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors.

Environment:

OS: Windows 11
Android Studio Version: Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch
AVD: Resizable Experimental API 35
Graphics: gfxstream

Questions:

How can I correctly install the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors if it’s not listed in the SDK Manager?
Are there any specific configurations required for this version of Android Studio to work with newer AVDs?
Could this be caused by a problem with the AVD itself or a misconfigured emulator?


How I fixed it:

I moved the .android folder to a new location on my D: drive (e.g., D:.android).
Updated the emulator configuration to reflect the new path.
Set the ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable to the new .android folder location (D:.android).
Restarted Android Studio and the emulator.

This fixed the issue by removing special characters from the path and ensuring the correct configuration.
